# Nine-patch image not repeating vertically in QVGA

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have created a Table layout with a number of rows and each row is assigned a background image to simulate rounded corner borders.   This works all fine except in QVGA where the top image doesn't repeat vertically.  Anyone run into this kind of problem? I have tried resaving the image and verifying the patch was correct.

[image: QVGA]
[image: HVGA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create two different 9-patches for mdpi and ldpi?

9-patch is not meant to be pre-scaled, sometimes it works but the theory says it shouldn't: when scaling (above all downscaling) the single black pixels of the edges get "shrinked" and then might become semi-transparent, breaking the 9-patch. This seems the case, with your middle/bottom images and the top one.

Comment: Uhm, I didn't think images were scaled, but were drawn exactly as they were.  I'll try duplication the image under the mdpi and ldpi folders.

Comment: I duplicate the images from drawable to drawable-ldpi and it resolved the issue.  Thanks.